# Why does AutoRecover ignore my dtsx package?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis

I'm having a very bad day. My laptop sometimes kills itself when I undock it. When that happened this morning, I was concerned that I might lose track of various notes that I had been keeping, but I certainly didn't expect to lose all of my changes on a complicated dtsx package. AutoRecover always presents any unsaved changes to me when Visual Studio restarts.

Not today.

Why on earth didn't AutoRecover preserve my SSIS package changes? Are only certain file types monitored? I found [where](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/02/14/did-you-know-where-visual-studio-saves-auto-recovered-files-in-the-case-of-an-unexpected-shutdown-151.aspx) those files should have been kept, and I went looking and found nothing. As I'm redoing all of the changes that I lost, I still see nothing in the backup directory. So even now, I can see that my changes are not being preserved.

I also verified that AutoRecover is turned on:
[image: From Tools --> Options]

Is this a problem with Integration Services projects? Is there any way to turn on AutoRecovery for these files?

Comment: Have you considered using some kind of source code control system?

Comment: @MattGibson We use TFS integrated with Visual Studio. This is not a question about how to save code, but about the safety net the IDE normally provides for code which has not been saved before a system crash.

Comment: Fair enough; you'd be surprised how often people aren't using one when they should be... I don't recall ever having to use Visual Studio's AutoRecover, so I can't be much help with that.